# contractible div or cell tables

Tags: html, css, width

Hi,

I have this code:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

what I want to do is to have #center display always at a minimum size whereas the other 2 will collapse and even disappear if the window is resized or seen on a smaller resolution.

This is my CSS:

```
div {display:table-cell;}
#left, #right {width:auto;}
#center {width:1460px;}
```

this will look fine on a 1080p screen but not on smaller such as a 1024 width screen because a scroll bar will show. In those cases I want #center to cover the whole width and the other 2 divs to collapse completely to make room. How can this be achieved with only html and css?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cain, I think this will be easier to show if I demo a smaller width for the center column. You can easily adjust the CSS to work at `1460px`.

```css
/* 
  1. Ensure center column has a fixed size
  2. If there is horizontal space greater than 460px,
     fill it equally with the left and right divisions
*/

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container > div {
  height: 40px;
}

#left, #right {
  flex: auto;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#center {
  flex-basis: 460px;
  background: black;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think your answer is closer to the solution because you showed me the usage of flex-basis which ended up being what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks, @Cain. If you're satisfied with my answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) like this:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#left, #right {
  background-color: gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#center {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">Left</div>
  <div id="center">Center</div>
  <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

- `flex-grow:1` allows the left and right divs to grow and take up any empty space.
- `min-width:0` allows the left and right divs to disappear completely even though they have content inside.
- `overflow:hidden` hides any content that is overflowing outside the left and right divs as the divs shrink.
- `min-width:500px` makes sure the center div will never shrink below a width 500px.
- The center div will never grow beyond 500px either, since the left and right divs will grow to take up the empty space.

**Additionally, if you want the left and right divs to have a maximum width and allow the center div to grow, add the following as well:**

- `flex-grow:1` to **#center** to allow it to grow.
- `max-width:50px` to **#left, #right** to cap the width of the left and right divs.

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/cnxhyytz/).

Comment: Your solution doesn't go all the way with flexbox. `flex-basis` and `flex: auto` are pure flexbox alternatives to assigning different `min-width` values.

Comment: @AndyHoffman There's no reason to go all the way with flexbox when using other CSS features makes the solution simpler and work better.

Comment: Simpler? Not if you understood how flexbox works. How exactly does your solution "work better"?

Comment: @AndyHoffman I am completely aware of all of flexbox's features. But code that reads `min-width:500px` states its intention very clearly.  Whereas code like `flex: 1 1 460px` does not.  Not to mention that your solution and the one I've stated in my answer actually produce different results.

Comment: @AndyHoffman No worries Andy :).  I upvoted your solution anyway because it works well.  Not sure which behavior the poster was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer too, Saeed.